heap Buffer Overflow error on Leetcode Largest Common Prefix problem
My solution for the largest common prefix problem compiles into an executable and runs on my machine, but I am getting a heap buffer overflow error when I try and run my solution on Leetcode.
Here is my solution to the problem:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

char* longestCommonPrefix(char** strs, int strsSize) {

    int numChars = 0;
    char tempChar = 'c';
    int minLen = strlen(strs[0]);
       for(int q=0; q < strsSize; q++) {
        if(strlen(strs[q]) < minLen) {
            minLen = strlen(strs[q]);
        }
    }

    char* tempArray = malloc(minLen * strsSize);
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < minLen; i++){
        for(int j=0; j < strsSize; j++) {
            tempChar = strs[j][i];
            tempArray[counter] = tempChar;
            counter++;
        }
    }

    bool isValid = true;
    int wordNum = 0;
    tempChar = tempArray[0];
    int numWords = strlen(tempArray)/minLen;
    char* tempFinal = malloc(numWords);
    counter=0;

    while(isValid) {
        for(int z=0; z < numWords; z++) {
          if(tempChar == tempArray[z+wordNum]) {
                if(z == numWords-1) {
                    tempFinal[counter] = tempChar;
                    counter++;
                    wordNum+= numWords;
                    tempChar = tempArray[z+wordNum];

                }
            }
            else {
                isValid = false;
                break;
            }

        }
    }
    return tempFinal;
}

int main() {

    char* strs[] = {"flowers","flow","flat"};
    int strsSize = sizeof(strs)/sizeof(strs[0]);

    printf("%s", longestCommonPrefix(strs, strsSize));

    return 0;
}

The error I am getting is the following:
Line 25:
=================================================================
==22==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x60200000007c at pc 0x7f20324813f2 bp 0x7ffc0f0d7360 sp 0x7ffc0f0d6b08
READ of size 13 at 0x60200000007c thread T0
    #0 0x7f20324813f1 in __interceptor_strlen ../../../../src/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors.inc:461
    #1 0x556791f5ac7b in longestCommonPrefix solution.c:25
    #2 0x556791f5a57c in main solution.c:25
    #3 0x7f2031b22d8f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29d8f) (BuildId: 490fef8403240c91833978d494d39e537409b92e)
    #4 0x7f2031b22e3f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29e3f) (BuildId: 490fef8403240c91833978d494d39e537409b92e)
    #5 0x556791f5a924 in _start (solution+0x1e924) (BuildId: cca3c917879ba1357e8d8e8528c32fa406d7c2ad)
0x60200000007c is located 0 bytes after 12-byte region [0x602000000070,0x60200000007c)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f20324f7fdf in __interceptor_malloc ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cpp:69
    #1 0x556791f5aadb in longestCommonPrefix solution.c:25
    #2 0x556791f5a57c in main solution.c:25
    #3 0x7f2031b22d8f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29d8f) (BuildId: 490fef8403240c91833978d494d39e537409b92e)
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow ../../../../src/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors.inc:461 in __interceptor_strlen
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x601ffffffd80: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x601ffffffe00: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x601ffffffe80: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x601fffffff00: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x601fffffff80: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x602000000000: fa fa 07 fa fa fa 05 fa fa fa 07 fa fa fa 00[04]
  0x602000000080: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x602000000100: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x602000000180: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x602000000200: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x602000000280: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
==22==ABORTING

Why am I able to compile it to an executable on my home machine, but Leetcode is unable to run it?

Leetcode may be testing with bigger inputs.

Calling malloc but not free is not really how you do proper memory management.

A program can have bugs without always showing obvious symptoms. Aside: Are you running with address sanitizer on your machine to help catch and identify some of those bugs that you might otherwise overlook or have trouble localizing their cause?

Where do you null terminate the so-called null-terminated string that you are returning from longestCommonPrefix()? Are you guaranteed to have enough room in the buffer for that required null terminator?

You never add a null terminator to tempArray, so strlen(tempArray) is invalid.

And since tempArray has been filled with minLen * strsSize chars, the apparent intended value for numWords is strsSize so there is no need for that calculation. However, this is essentially unrelated to the size you will needed for the tempFinal buffer, though that is what you are using it for. I don't yet see why your are bothering with tempArray yet, it seems unnecessary for this problem.

You are not using AddressSanitizer on your home machine. Add that and you'll get this there too when you run the program.

To simplify it, you could also just return the length of the longest common prefix and let printf truncate it. Example

You don't need to do three passes of O(strsSize * length) each, allocate and copy O(entire input) (then leak it) — seems like you are over-complicating things. @TedLyngmo I think this forgets when the strings are all the same.

@Neil How so? It will then return the same as strlen.

@TedLyngmo Ah, from the outer for. This is way more efficient. My bad.

@StrydrSilverberg Please fill in the gaps. We're answering your question so please chime in.


tempArray is one byte too short to fit a null terminator and ...
... you don't null terminate it which you must do because you later do strlen(tempArray).
int numWords = strlen(tempArray) / minLen; is confusing. What is numWords supposed to be if not strsSize that you already have? I can't see how they can be different.
With the above point in mind, char* tempFinal = malloc(numWords); is obviosly a problem. If you send in 3 strings, this will allocate 3 bytes, which can't fit a longest common prefix longer than 2 (+ the null terminator).
The while loop using numWords and wordNum is broken beyond repair, probably because you think numWords is something it is not and tempChar = tempArray[z + wordNum]; will therefore access tempArray out of bounds even if you make it one byte bigger to make room for the null terminator.


In real code I would just return the length of the longest common prefix and let the user decide what to do with that information:
size_t longestCommonPrefix(char *strs[], size_t strsSize) {
    size_t len = 0;
    for (; strs[0][len]; ++len) {
        // return as soon as a char in one of the strings does not match
        // the other (in the same position):
        for (size_t sidx = 1; sidx < strsSize; ++sidx) {
            // difference found, return the length
            if (strs[0][len] != strs[sidx][len]) return len;
        }
    }
    return len; // no diff found, same as strlen(strs[0])
}

Printing the longest common prefix without allocations would then be easily done with printf:
printf("%.*s\n", (int)longestCommonPrefix(strs, strsSize), strs[0]);

But, since it's Leetcode, I expect that you are bound to a rather lousy interface. In that case I'd take advantage of the non-constness of the strings by using the same algorithm as above but replace the position where the difference is found with a \0 in one of the strings and return that:
char *longestCommonPrefix(char *strs[], size_t strsSize) {
    for (size_t len = 0; strs[0][len]; ++len) {
        for (size_t sidx = 1; sidx < strsSize; ++sidx) {
            if (strs[0][len] != strs[sidx][len]) {
                // difference found, truncate one string and return it
                strs[0][len] = '\0';
                return strs[0];
            }
        }
    }
    return strs[0]; // no diff, return one of the strings as-is
}

Unless Leetcode feeds your function with string literals or const char[]s where the const-ness has been cast away, this will work. It's a terrible function though because it will change one of the strings if needed and a user will probably not expect that (unless the behavior is well documented). This is the kind of bad code that solves toy problems at Leetcode that you will have to unlearn when doing real world programming.

Unfortunately, your code is needlessly complex (and, therefore, error prone):

Repeated use of strlen. In fact, no strlen calls need be used. Testing for the "current" char is zero is faster/simpler.
No need for malloc. A static fixed buffer can be returned because the maximum length string is known (e.g. 200)

From: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Programming_Style


Don't patch bad code – rewrite it.


Here is a refactored version. It is annotated:
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXSTR      200

char *
longestCommonPrefix(char **strs, int strsSize)
{
    int curchr;  // current char in string being tested
    char *cp;  // pointer to current string being tested
    int match = 0;  // length of prefix
    static char retbuf[MAXSTR + 1];

    for (int chridx = 0;  chridx < MAXSTR + 1;  ++chridx) {
        int stop = 0;

        // no strings specified (necessary???)
        if (strsSize <= 0)
            break;

        // point to first string in list
        char *cp = strs[0];

        // get the Nth char as the current prefix char
        int prechr = cp[chridx];

        // we can't be any longer than the shortest string (which just happens
        // to be the first)
        if (prechr == 0)
            break;

        // test all strings against the current prefix char
        for (int stridx = 1;  stridx < strsSize;  ++stridx) {
            // point to start of current string in list of strings
            cp = strs[stridx];

            // get current char in string being tested
            curchr = cp[chridx];

            // is current char in current string a match?
            stop = (curchr != prechr);

            // no, stop now
            if (stop)
                break;

            // are we at the end of the string? (i.e. we can only match against
            // the shortest string)
            stop = (curchr == 0);

            // yes, stop now
            if (stop)
                break;
        }

        // stop now
        if (stop)
            break;

        // add the current char as valid for prefix result
        retbuf[match++] = prechr;
    }

    retbuf[match] = 0;

    return retbuf;
}

void
dotest(char **test)
{

    char **av = test;
    for (;  *av != NULL;  ++av);

    printf("%s\n", longestCommonPrefix(test, av - test));
}

#define DOTEST(_strs...) \
    do { \
        char *test[] = { _strs }; \
        dotest(test); \
    } while (0)

int
main(void)
{

    DOTEST("flowers", "flow", "flat", NULL);
    DOTEST("flowers", NULL);
    DOTEST("", NULL);
    DOTEST(NULL);
    DOTEST("back", "backers", "backgammon", NULL);

    return 0;
}

